# chromatic number in graph coloring

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, proof-writing, coloring, bipartite-graphs

It is given that we have N points arranged along a circle and $N \geq k(k+1)$. $G_k$ is the graph we get after connecting every point out of $N$ on the circle to it's $k$ nearest neighboring points in all directions of the circle.

I have to prove that $$ \chi(G_k) = (k+1) \text{ if n is divisible by k+1}$$
$$ =\text{    }(k+2) \text{       else     } $$

Here, $\chi$ denotes the chromatic number of a graph, although I am aware that it essentially denotes the different colors for graph coloring , I am not sure as to how I would get the desired result.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are the points are evenly arranged around the circle? Do you want $k$ to be even?

Comment: @CalvinLin although it's not mentioned expclictly, however if you have a possible approach by taking that assumption, please do share.

Comment: So, if $k=1$ we connect each point to its neighbor on the left and get an $n$ cycle, whose chromatic number is $2$ when $n$ is even and $3$ when $n$ is odd, in agreement with the statement of the theorem.  If $k$ is $2$ we connect each point to $2$ points on its left and $2$ on its right.

Comment: Presumably colorings that witness the chromatic number are of the form: start with one point and go around the circle, running through the $k+1$ or $k+2$ colors cyclically until we're out of points. Proving that these are valid colorings would be half (literaly) the battle.

Comment: @saulspatz "we connect each point to its neighbor on the left and get an n cycle" -> I would have said that we're connecting each point to it's 2 nearest neighboring points. Though, with your interpretation, that makes the formula work for $k = 1$. Maybe the phrasing should've been "connect every point to the $k$ nearest neighbors on the left".

Comment: @CalvinLin Well, if you connect each point to its neighbor on the left, that's the same as connecting it to its two nearest neighbors, isn't it?  They're on a circle.  I think that in the problem statement, "in all directions" should read "in both directions".  Or are you simply saying that I could have phrased it better?  I agree with that.

Comment: @saulspatz Ah no. The ambiguity in the problem's phrasing boiled down to: Connecting to "k=1 nearest neighbors on the left" is the same as "connect to k=2 nearest nearest neighbors". I was trying to make explicit that the former seems to be what is intended.